# How to make multiple items of different heights that shrink to content and don't overflow their wrapper?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with two items - which themselves are flex containers (direction column)

```css
html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            #outer_wrapper {
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                right:0px;
                bottom:0px;
                margin:30px;
            }

            .pane_container {
                display: flex;
                max-height: 100%;
            }
            .pane_item {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 300px;
            }
            .pane_scroll {
                overflow: auto;
            }
            .pane_header {
                height: 40px;
                flex: none;
            }
            .pane_footer {
                height: 40px;
                flex: none;
            }
            .scroll_item {
                height: 30px;
                margin: 10px;
            }

            #outer_wrapper { background: grey; }
            .pane_item { border: 3px solid black; }
            .pane_header { background: red; }
            .pane_scroll { background: yellow; }
            .pane_footer { background: green; }
            .scroll_item { background: orange; border: 1px solid green;}
```

```html
 <body>
        <div id="outer_wrapper">
            <div class="pane_container">
                <div class="pane_item pane_item_1">
                    <div class="pane_header">header 1</div>
                    <div class="pane_scroll">
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 1 </div>
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 2 </div>
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 3 </div>
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 4 </div>
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 5 </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pane_footer">footer 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="pane_item pane_item_2">
                    <div class="pane_header">header 2</div>
                    <div class="pane_scroll">
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 1 </div>
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 2 </div>
                        <div class="scroll_item"> Content 3 </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pane_footer">footer 2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

The idea is that when the outer wrapper's height is reduced, each item has an inner div that scrolls vertically. So far so good. (Resizing the results pane in the fiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/bckquv17/7/

However I would like each item to shrink to fit its content rather than expand to the tallest. To do this, I gather, I can add `align-items:flex-start` to the main flex container.

When I do this, the flex items do indeed shrink, but are no longer constrained by the outer wrapper, and thus they overflow rather than produce inner scrolls.

https://jsfiddle.net/bckquv17/9/

How do I set it up such that the flex items shrink to their content and also do not overflow when the outer wrappers height is reduced?

Comment: Hi Nymor, you have invalid CSS; your .box-sizing class seems to be nested inside another selector declaration. Can you fix that? Also, you can create a runnable code snippet with the code in your post (just like on JSFiddle) - when editing, click the icon in the WYSIWYG editor just to the right of the 'upload image' icon.

Comment: I've removed the box-sizing error - even if correct it wasn't needed anyway I think ... and thanks for the explanation of the code snippet stuff - although as the wrapper is dynamic in size I don't see a way to demostrate the issue the way the fiddles do - but it's there anyway

Comment: The Stack Snippet (as it is often called) does have some limitations; you can view responsive/dynamic sizing by clicking the "full page" link at the top left of the preview after running it, then un-maximizing your browser window and resizing it smaller or larger to resize the viewport of the Snippet.